# MAX aggregation of rows in Webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

I can't figure out how to show only example results for a field in a WebI table.

I have a data set in WebI with agents and agents' companies, among other things.  The data set contains multiple companies for some agents, or with slight variations (e.g. "ACME Co." v. "ACME Company").  I want my report table to show each agent only once, with one of the values for the company next to it rather than new lines for each agent/company combination.

So the data is like:
Agent | Company
-|-
Agent A| Company 1
Agent A| Company 2
Agent B| Company 3
Agent B| Company 4

...and I want my table to show only:
Agent | Company
-|-
Agent A| Company 1
Agent B| Company 3

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What determines which Company should be displayed for an agent?  And in your desired result you show Company 2 with Agent B but that combination doesn't exist in the raw data.

Comment: Yep, Company 2 was a typo.  It isn't critical which company is shown next to an agent.  The important thing is that if company is blank sometimes and filled in other times it would show a value.  First and last formulas don't see to do it right for blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have no other objects in your report block that are nonunique within the Agent, you can simply use:

```
=[Agent]
=Max([Company])
```